# Filter files by current directory from ComboBox to a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combobox that lists directories and I have a listbox that shows files in the directory that is currently selected in the combobox. I want it so when you change the selected item in the combobox, the listbox updates with the new files.

How do I achieve this?

My current attempt:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\guest\Desktop\test");
    DirectoryInfo[] folders = dinfo.GetDirectories();
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles();

    cbobox.DataSource = folders;

    foreach(FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        lstbox.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How can I code to list files from selected folder by combo box.

Comment: Just call the code you provided as a handler to [ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `dinfo` to the path in the `combobox`.

Assuming your combo box just has the string of the directory

```
dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(combobox.SelectedItem);
```

and the rest of your code stays the same

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(combobox.SelectedItem);
    DirectoryInfo[] folders = dinfo.GetDirectories();
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles();

    cbobox.DataSource = folders;

    foreach(FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        lstbox.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to change it when a new item in the combobox is selected, you'd need to use an event.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshList();
    combobox.SelectedIndexChanged += 
        new System.EventHandler(ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
}

private void RefreshList() 
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(combobox.SelectedItem);
    DirectoryInfo[] folders = dinfo.GetDirectories();
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles();

    cbobox.DataSource = folders;

    foreach(FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        lstbox.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}

private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshList();
}
```

## Please read

This code is assuming your combo box has the name `combobox`, and the strings in the combo box are the full path (or relative path) to the directory you want to filter by. 
If it's not you'll need to adapt to serve your purpose.

Comment: You shouldnt feed the pigeons.   [Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281795/585968)

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is this question a duplicate? EDIT: tbh I didn't know bad question was a thing..